# parallel sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, sparse-matrix

For sparse matrix multiplication, it is less efficiency than dense one mainly because more time is spent on locating and seeking elements in memory rather than CPU computation.

I am using matlab, and here, I need to do a very sparse matrix multiplication with a dense one, i.e. *S* times *D* where *S* is sparse and *D* is dense.

Then, my questions are that

1. if D has *k* columns, and do S times *D(:,k)* in parallel for each *k*, will it be faster than matlab default routine S times D?
2. if so, is it better for me to write .mex files, and do multi-threads computation in them?

Thanks very much~

Comment: Matlab's matrix multiplication routines are practically the fastest algorithms known in CPU. If S and D are very big, you may need to consider GPU...

Comment: Take option 2 only if you are confident that you can do a better job than the Matlab development team. Most of the performance-critical parts of Matlab are already implemented as highly-optimised compiled and multi-threaded code. Some of them are actually implemented as calls to libraries, such as Intel's MKL, which are themselves highly-optimised. So you may have to beat Intel's developers too.

Comment: Thanks for ur answers, yeah... I don't want to spend too much time on programming. Indeed, I am also considering using GPU to do sparse matrix multiplication. Anyway, I will try cuSPARSE first.

Comment: Unless you reuse the matrix many times, eg Krylov methods, moving data across the PCI bus is going to render the GPU performance almost useless.